# Facebook - Find out who shared a share

Tags: facebook

Alice posts an item on her timeline. Bob shares it on his page. Carol shares Bob's share. Is there any way in Graph API  that I can work out that Carol's share came through Bob?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate. And have you tried the Facebook Docs? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Comment: I can't find anything relevant in the docs and I'm not aware of any duplicates of this after I did extensive searching both places.

Comment: I'm sure I saw something like this a while back. I'm not sure you can do it now, since they've upped the security and privacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this off, @Shrink is right, it seems to have been possible in the original Graph API but that has been closed off now.